# Drawing smooth lines to a grid [2D array] in Conway's Game of Life

Tags: java, arrays, graphics, conways-game-of-life

**tl;dr** What is a very fast way to use coordinate points to draw smooth lines in an array? Note: reading the below information will probably provide some much-needed context.

I am currently working on an implementation of Conway's Game of Life. I use a Mouse Listener [mouseDragged, specifically] to two points at a time, and pass them into this method:

```
     public void findIndexSmoothed(int x, int y, int nx, int ny)
    {
        int size1 = size / 2 + 1; // radius
        size1 *= brush;
        int searchMargin = 10; // how many squares are checked within a certain              
        double slope;
        // ((x/size) -50 >0) ? ((x/size) -50) : 0
        // Optimizes performance at the expense of function
        // UPDATE: a simple if/else reduced function loss to nominal levels
        if (x + 2.5 < nx)
        {
            slope = (((double) ny - y) / (nx - x));
            for (int i = 0; i < sY; i++)
            {
    for (int j = ((x / size) - searchMargin > 0) ? ((x / size)     - searchMargin) : 0; j <  
sX; j++)                {
                    for (double c = x; c <= nx; c += 1)
                    {
                        if ((valCoord[i][j][0] >= c - size1 && valCoord[i][j][0] <= c + size1)
                                && (valCoord[i][j][1] >= ((slope * (c - x)) + y) - size1 && valCoord[i][j][1] <= ((slope * (c - x)) + y)
                                        + size1))
                        {
                            flagVals[i][j] = true;
                            actualVals[i][j] = true;
                            cachedVals[i][j] = true;
                            cachedVals[i + 1][j + 1] = true;
                            cachedVals[i + 1][j] = true;
                            cachedVals[i + 1][j - 1] = true;
                            cachedVals[i][j + 1] = true;
                            cachedVals[i][j - 1] = true;
                            cachedVals[i - 1][j + 1] = true;
                            cachedVals[i - 1][j - 1] = true;
                            cachedVals[i - 1][j + 1] = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else if (x - 2.5 > nx)
        {
            slope = (((double) ny - y) / (nx - x));
            int d = ((x / size) + searchMargin < sX) ? ((x / size) + searchMargin) : sX;
            for (int i = 0; i < sY; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < d; j++)
                {
                    for (double c = nx; c <= x; c += 1)
                    {
                        if ((valCoord[i][j][0] >= c - size1 && valCoord[i][j][0] <= c + size1)
                                && (valCoord[i][j][1] >= ((slope * (c - x)) + y) - size1 && valCoord[i][j][1] <= ((slope * (c - x)) + y)
                                        + size1))
                        {
                            flagVals[i][j] = true;
                            actualVals[i][j] = true;
                            cachedVals[i][j] = true;
                            cachedVals[i + 1][j + 1] = true;
                            cachedVals[i + 1][j] = true;
                            cachedVals[i + 1][j - 1] = true;
                            cachedVals[i][j + 1] = true;
                            cachedVals[i][j - 1] = true;
                            cachedVals[i - 1][j + 1] = true;
                            cachedVals[i - 1][j - 1] = true;
                            cachedVals[i - 1][j + 1] = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (ny > y)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < sY; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = ((x / size) - searchMargin > 0) ? ((x / size) - searchMargin) : 0; j < sX; j++)
                    {
                        for (double c = y; c <= ny; c++)
                        {
                            if ((valCoord[i][j][0] >= x - size1 && valCoord[i][j][0] <= x + size1)
                                    && (valCoord[i][j][1] >= c - size1 && valCoord[i][j][1] <= c + size1))
                            {
                                flagVals[i][j] = true;
                                actualVals[i][j] = true;
                                cachedVals[i][j] = true;
                                cachedVals[i + 1][j + 1] = true;
                                cachedVals[i + 1][j] = true;
                                cachedVals[i + 1][j - 1] = true;
                                cachedVals[i][j + 1] = true;
                                cachedVals[i][j - 1] = true;
                                cachedVals[i - 1][j + 1] = true;
                                cachedVals[i - 1][j - 1] = true;
                                cachedVals[i - 1][j + 1] = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < sY; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = ((x / size) - searchMargin > 0) ? ((x / size) - searchMargin) : 0; j < sX; j++)
                    {
                        for (double c = ny; c <= y; c++)
                        {
                            if ((valCoord[i][j][0] >= x - size1 && valCoord[i][j][0] <= x + size1)
                                    && (valCoord[i][j][1] >= c - size1 && valCoord[i][j][1] <= c + size1))
                            {
                                flagVals[i][j] = true;
                                actualVals[i][j] = true;
                                cachedVals[i][j] = true;
                                cachedVals[i + 1][j + 1] = true;
                                cachedVals[i + 1][j] = true;
                                cachedVals[i + 1][j - 1] = true;
                                cachedVals[i][j + 1] = true;
                                cachedVals[i][j - 1] = true;
                                cachedVals[i - 1][j + 1] = true;
                                cachedVals[i - 1][j - 1] = true;
                                cachedVals[i - 1][j + 1] = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Okay, if your eyes aren't bleeding yet, allow me to explain what exactly this behemoth does. First, it calculates which way the mouse is being dragged. Let's say it's going right. Then it calculates the slope of the line formed by the two points, and goes through these three nested for loops.

```
            for (int i = 0; i < sY; i++)
            {
    for (int j = ((x / size) - searchMargin > 0) ? ((x / size)     - searchMargin) : 0; j <  
sX; j++)                {
                    for (double c = x; c <= nx; c += 1)
                    {
                        if ((valCoord[i][j][0] >= c - size1 && valCoord[i][j][0] <= c + size1)
                                && (valCoord[i][j][1] >= ((slope * (c - x)) + y) - size1 && valCoord[i][j][1] <= ((slope * (c - x)) + y)
                                        + size1))
                        {
                            flagVals[i][j] = true;
                            actualVals[i][j] = true;
                            cachedVals[i][j] = true;
                            cachedVals[i + 1][j + 1] = true;
                            cachedVals[i + 1][j] = true;
                            cachedVals[i + 1][j - 1] = true;
                            cachedVals[i][j + 1] = true;
                            cachedVals[i][j - 1] = true;
                            cachedVals[i - 1][j + 1] = true;
                            cachedVals[i - 1][j - 1] = true;
                            cachedVals[i - 1][j + 1] = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

It loops entirely through the vertical portion of the array, and through a subsection of it horizontally. The last for loop goes through every X-coordinate between the two points. The if-statement plugs that X value into the equation of the line, finds a corresponding Y value, and checks an array of coordinate points for a match. If it finds one, it then sets the array used for processing [and it's counterpart] equal to true at that location. (You can ignore the cachedVals, that's part of an optimization for the grid, and not really relevant to the question)

On a fairly small grid, say 100x100, this works perfectly, with almost 0 lag. However, I am using much larger grids [approx 3000x2500], that can contain as many as 7 million positions. Any ideas on how to optimize [or completely change] this code?

EDIT: So I got this working a while ago, but I forgot to post it here. Should anybody else have a similar problem, here's my implementation:

```
public void findIndexSmoothedII(int x, int y, int nx, int ny) // A custom implementation of Bresenham's Line
                                                                // Algorithm
{
    // preliminary brush size and super-sampling calculations
    int use = (size / 2 + 1) * brush / size;
    int shift = superSampled ? 1 : 0;
    // Determine distance between points in the X and Y axes, regardless of direction
    int dx = Math.abs(nx - x), dy = Math.abs(ny - y);
    // Determine what type of movement to take along line, based on direction
    int sx = x < nx ? 1 : -1, sy = y < ny ? 1 : -1;
    // threshold of offset before incrementing
    int err = (dx > dy ? dx : -dy) / 2;
    // The (sX,sY) values converted from the raw coordinates
    int xS, yS;
    while (true)
    {
        // if Both x and y have been incremented to the location of the second point, line is drawn and the algorithim
        // can end
        if (x == nx && y == ny)
            break;
        // Determine where cursor is in terms of (sY,sX) and handle border cases for X-Axis
        if ((x / size) - use > 0 && (x / size) + use < sX)
            xS = x / size;
        else if ((x / size) - use > 0 && (x / size) + use >= sX)
            xS = 5000;
        else
            xS = -5000;
        // Determine where cursor is in terms of (sY,sX) and handle border cases for Y-Axis
        if ((y / size) - use > 0 && (y / size) + use < sY)
            yS = y / size;
        else if ((y / size) - use > 0 && (y / size) + use >= sY)
            yS = 5000;
        else
            yS = -5000;
        // Below loops are responsible for array access and accounting for brush size
        for (int j = yS - (use << shift); j < yS + (use << shift); j++)
        {
            for (int i = xS - (use << shift); i < xS + (use << shift); i++)
            {
                if (i < sX - 3 && i > 2 && j > 2 && j < sY - 3)
                {
                    flagVals[j][i] = true;
                    actualVals[j][i] = true;
                    cachedVals[j][i] = true;
                    cachedVals[j + 1][i + 1] = true;
                    cachedVals[j + 1][i] = true;
                    cachedVals[j + 1][i - 1] = true;
                    cachedVals[j][i + 1] = true;
                    cachedVals[j][i - 1] = true;
                    cachedVals[j - 1][i + 1] = true;
                    cachedVals[j - 1][i - 1] = true;
                    cachedVals[j - 1][i + 1] = true;
                }
            }
        }
        // determine where to point to next
        int e2 = err;
        if (e2 > -dx)
        {
            err -= dy;
            x += sx;
        }
        if (e2 < dy)
        {
            err += dx;
            y += sy;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you know the end-points of the line, why are there three nested loops?  I'd expect you to be able to draw the line with one.

Comment: Also, once you know the slope, you don't have to calculate it in the inner loop. Calculate the slope outside, and just add it to `y` each time you move `x` one cell. Just `x++;`, and `y+=slope;`  Add a case for vertical lines, though (slope = infinity).  You'll have to add some cleverness for slopes that are near-vertical, too, to ensure you get a continuous line.

Comment: Finally, just for fun, making an enormous grid for Life is easy but wasteful of system resources.  Life tends to have clusters of cells, and lots of space in between.  Consider that once two live cells are more than one cell apart, they no longer influence each other. What if you had a gun, and it created a glider.  After something like 10 generations, it would not longer be influenced by the gun.   Why not represent the glider on its own 6x6 sub grid?  Consider a Life game supporting a Grid class that manages dynamically-sized, self-contained Lifes.

Comment: @Tony The reason two loops are need is that I am passing in coordinate points, and I need to convert them to the format actualVals is in [# of cells vs. where they are on the screen]. The way I have done this is by looking at every position in the array within a certain area, and determining whether it rests on the line formed by the two points. Note how there is a 3D array of points. I don't think, with this setup, I can use < 3 loops.

Comment: And since you mention it, you may notice the cachedVals array in there. The purpose of this is to drastically reduce time spent processing empty areas of the grid, by only processing living cells and their neighbors. I think that this solution is _similar_ to what you mentioned.

Comment: I can see one loop from the start point to the end point.  In the easy case, you loop from x1 to x2 incrementing by 1, and adding the slope to the current y value.  The reality is, when you have a slope that's too great, you'll get something unsightly, like (0,0) and (0,5).  So you may need a loop to crawl up the `y` axis also, so that you'd have (0,0)(1,1)(1,2)(1,3)(1,4)(1,5).  But this should still be lightning-fast.

Comment: The challenging suggestion for the Grid class was to make it possible to have large numbers of widely dispersed cells without creating an nxm array that includes them all.  For example, if you had 4 gliders 1,000,000 cells apart, you might need a 1,000,000x1,000,000 array.  With the Grid idea, you'd need 4 Grid instances each managing a 5x5 array.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement Bresenham's line algorithm (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm). Its very simple and you can use the array indices directly as coordinates.

Comment: The indices in actualVals? I'm not sure how I would do that, as I am passing in coordinate points. If you could give me a better idea of the implementation you have in mind, that would be great.

Comment: @Azar Come on, the wiki even has *sample implementations* (which are almost good to copy and paste). They work with exactly that: coordinates. Where is the problem?

Comment: Yes I've looked at those (none of which are in Java, by the way), and yes the use coordinates, but therein lies the problem! I need a clean way to convert the coordinates passed in to the format actualVals uses, which is # of positions in the array. Anyway, I have an idea, and I'll see if I can bring it to fruition. If so, I will mark this as the answer.

Comment: I don't think adding curly brackets to a pascal or basic implemention shouldn't be *too* demanding. And I don't see the problem you have with the format or your arrays either, think of the indices as (x, y) instead of (i, j) - just different names, same concept.

Comment: What you're suggesting will only work if each grid member is one pixel wide, which is not [always] the case. I intend to rework the valCoord array such that the indices will be the X,Y coords, and they will contain data that points to the corresponding location in actualVals.

Comment: Your implementation of plot(x, y) as defined by the line algorithm can easily set multiple points (think of it as a brush) if you need that. From your wall of code one can't really derive how its interpreted and displayed on screen. And how can a grid member *not* be *always* one pixel wide - you use boolean arrays, a grid member can only be on or off by definition. You probably have something in mind you didn't describe in the scope of the question, involving multiple cells.

Comment: I have given the user the option to choose from multiple sizes of grids, from 16px wide to 1px wide. Just give me a while, and I will see if I can work out an implementation.

Comment: Yep, a brush concept just as I suspected. Abstract it away into the plot() method, heck you could just pass the plot method a two-dimensional array to be used as the "brush" and define arbitrarily shaped brushes that way. Think of the cells as white/black pixels and imagine it graphically. With another parameter you can have even different "drawing modes" (like or, and, xor).